# Python - Trying to join 2 excel files together on multiple conditions and failing

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Seeking some help here.

I have 2 excel files that I want to join together based upon multiple columns being a match.  The primary file "Tra" will have several corresponding rows of data in the second Excel file "Pr".

The problem I run into is that it says "TypeError: Can only merge Series or Dataframe objects, a <class 'str'> was passed.

Any thoughts on how to resolve?   My ideal end state is to have all rows from file with all columns "Tra" and then all columns from "Pr" for each corresponding row that matches in the same file.

```
import pandas as pd
    
    tra_path = "/path/to/Tra.xlsx"
    pr_path = "/path/to/Pr.xlsx"
    output_path = "/path/to/output"
    
   tra_df = pd.read_excel(tra_path)
    pr_df = pd.read_excel(pr_path)
    
    merged_df = tra_df.merge(
        pr_df,
        left_on=["E", "G", "K", "L"],
        right_on=["AP", "AA", "Y", "R"],
        how="inner"
    )
    
    output_file = "/path/to/output/Merged.xlsx"
    merged_df.to_excel(output_file, index=False)
    print(f"Merged results saved to '{output_file}'")
```

Comment: Please post the complete error message and traceback, if possible.